# Kivy - Label that displays Python variable and automatically updates when variable is changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

I've been trying to find an answer to this question, to no avail.

I have a Label object which needs to display a global Python variable. However, they initially only show the text that is set in the Kivy file, and won't change unless a button is pressed. I need the Label to show the variable immediately, as well as update automatically when it's changed.

Here's an example:

```
"""Hopefully this is a better example of what I need."""
# ============================== Import Modules ==============================

# ===== Import Kivy =====
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

# ============================================================================


# =========================== Variable Definitions ===========================

# ===== Define ScreenManager =====
sm = ScreenManager()

# ============================================================================


# ========================== Define screen classes ===========================

class InputScreen(Screen):
    """Input stuff into text boxes."""

    var1 = StringProperty()
    var2 = StringProperty()
    var3 = StringProperty()
    # Take the input from these text boxes and show them on the next screen


class DisplayScreen(Screen):
    """Show content from previous text boxes."""

# ============================================================================


# ============================= Define main app ==============================

class MainApp(App):
    """Class for main app."""

    def build(self):
        """Build app."""
        # Add screens to ScreenManager
        sm.add_widget(InputScreen(name='input'))
        sm.add_widget(DisplayScreen(name='display'))

        # Display current screen
        return sm

# ============================================================================


# ===== Run program =====
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<InputScreen>:
    var1: var1_input.text
    var2: var2_input.text
    var3: var3_input.text
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}
        text: "var1 ="
    TextInput:
        id: var1_input
        font_size: 24
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 96, 48
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.77}
        multiline: False
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.65}
        text: "var2 ="
    TextInput:
        id: var2_input
        font_size: 24
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 96, 48
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.57}
        multiline: False
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
        text: "var3 ="
    TextInput:
        id: var3_input
        font_size: 24
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 96, 48
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.37}
        multiline: False
    Button:
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 120, 50
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.15}
        text: "Continue"
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.current = 'display'

<DisplayScreen>:
    Button:
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 80, 50
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1}
        text: "Back"
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.manager.current = 'input'
    Label:
        id: label1
        text_to_display:"(this should show var1 from previous screen)"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
        text: "var1 = " + self.text_to_display
    Label:
        id: label2
        text_to_display:"(this should show var2 from previous screen)"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        text: "var2 = " + self.text_to_display
    Label:
        id: label3
        text_to_display:"(this should show var3 from previous screen)"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        text: "var3 = " + self.text_to_display
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use `Kivy Properties`.

- Add the variables as `StringProperties` inside your `App`.
- Set the variables to be updated every time you change the input text..
- Set the display labels to display the variables...

Your code, working:
The .py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

sm = ScreenManager()


class InputScreen(Screen):
    """Input stuff into text boxes."""


class DisplayScreen(Screen):
    """Show content from previous text boxes."""


class MainApp(App):
    """Class for main app."""
    var1 = StringProperty()
    var2 = StringProperty()
    var3 = StringProperty()

    def build(self):
        """Build app."""
        # Add screens to ScreenManager
        sm.add_widget(InputScreen(name='input'))
        sm.add_widget(DisplayScreen(name='display'))

        # Display current screen
        return sm


# ===== Run program =====
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

...and the .kv:

```py
<InputScreen>:
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}
        text: "var1 ="
    TextInput:
        id: var1_input
        font_size: 24
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 96, 48
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.77}
        multiline: False
        # when the text changes, write it to the variable
        on_text: app.var1 = self.text
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.65}
        text: "var2 ="
    TextInput:
        id: var2_input
        font_size: 24
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 96, 48
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.57}
        multiline: False
        # when the text changes, write it to the variable
        on_text: app.var2 = self.text
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
        text: "var3 ="
    TextInput:
        id: var3_input
        font_size: 24
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 96, 48
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.37}
        multiline: False
        # when the text changes, write it to the variable
        on_text: app.var3 = self.text
    Button:
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 120, 50
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.15}
        text: "Continue"
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.current = 'display'

<DisplayScreen>:
    Button:
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 80, 50
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1}
        text: "Back"
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.manager.current = 'input'
    Label:
        id: label1
        text_to_display:"(this should show var1 from previous screen)"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
        text: "var1 = " + app.var1  # get the updated value
    Label:
        id: label2
        text_to_display:"(this should show var2 from previous screen)"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        text: "var2 = " + app.var2  # get the updated value
    Label:
        id: label3
        text_to_display:"(this should show var3 from previous screen)"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        text: "var3 = " + app.var3  # get the updated value
```

Comment: I need it to display the variables *immediately*, without input. This has to load the value from the variable since, in my actual application, there's no way to know what the value is ahead of time.

Comment: Maybe I did a poor job of explaining it... I'll make a better example and edit this comment to add a link to a Github Gist for it. Keep an eye out.

Comment: Couldn't edit my last comment, so... [Here you go.](https://gist.github.com/Offbox/939f66fbcfea015e6bf48a2b3ac416b8)

Comment: I can answer your question, but you have to update your code too. Edit your question and replace your code with the one from the gist.. Otherwise, it will be really confusing for the people that read it... :o)

Comment: @Offbox check the updated answer and please, update the question code too...

Comment: Updated the post and got the code working in my project! As a side question (I don't think it warrants a separate post, since it's so simple) how can I change the value of one of those App variables from within Python? I've tried `App.my_var = "This doesn't work."` and `App.my_var = StringProperty("This doesn't work either.")`. I'd like to also be able to change those values via functions and whatnot, as opposed to *only* through TextInput like your answer.

Comment: @Offbox You can save the running app in a variable like this: `self.app = App.get_running_app()`. After that you can change the vars by `self.app.my_var = "Whatever"`